# Missing Push Notification Entitlement issues

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I'm getting the following error from apple when I Archive my app. How do I fix this?

ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment' entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the 'aps-environment' entitlement. Xcode does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor's Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH6-SW1.

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

Comment: I simply solved this issue by this steps: stackoverflow.com/a/71478084/11675817

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image]
open your project target and then go to Signing & Capabilities then click in the + Capability and select Push Notification it should appear to you like the image

Comment: how do i remove the push notification from the capabilities ??

Comment: press this X button at the end of the line of Push Notification, I selected it with red color in the image

[1]: https://ibb.co/Rvj5HJj

Comment: Also make sure that push notifications is selected and configured in identifiers settings on developer console. If not then configure it and reimport the provisioning profile.